# Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner server how to connect it to Artifactory repository and get stubs artifact file via REST?

Tags: spring-cloud

I've create REST service which should connect to Artifactory.com repository, find stubs of contract tests artifact and get it. But when I start app and use GET method it doesn't returned any information (only {} in response). What parameters or else may be I didn't write or write wrong? Thanks for help.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
        repositoryRoot = "http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/exampleapp",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,
        ids = "com.exampleproject:users:develop-20190806.111405-21:stubs:8555")
public class StubRunnerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StubRunnerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/stubs", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class StabsController {

    @StubRunnerPort("com.exampleproject:users")
    private int port;

    private final StubRunning stubRunning;

    @Autowired
    public StabsController(StubRunning stubRunning) {
        this.stubRunning = stubRunning;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Map<String, Integer> getStabs() {
        return stubRunning.runStubs().toIvyToPortMapping();
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
stubrunner:
  work-offline: true
  cloud.stubbed.discovery.enabled: false
```

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-starter-web.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version>
        <spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner.version>
        <spring-cloud-stream.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-web.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Expected result: 
Applying GET method to link `localhost:8080/stubs/` will returned stubs of contract tests.
Actual result:
Applying GET method to link `localhost:8080/stubs/` returns `{}`

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, why do you set the versions of all of your libraries manually? Please go to start.spring.io, generate a project that will contain the BOMs and those will set the versions automatically for you.

Coming back to the main question I think you should remove

```
stubrunner:
  work-offline: true
```

cause it makes no sense - there's no such property anymore.

Please also change

`repositoryRoot = "http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/exampleapp",`

to

`repositoryRoot = "http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local",`

or sth like this. It has to point to the root of where your JARs can be found. For repo.spring.io that would be e.g. https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/

BTW here you have an example of such a server - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/stub-runner-boot/

UPDATE: In the presented repository a SPEL expression was used from inside the `ids` property. It does not seem to be supported ATM.

Comment: Hi, Marcin. Thank you for answer. Could you please specify repository root for stubs? I have next link to jar file in artifactory: ```http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/exampleproject/com/exampleapp/users/develop-SNAPSHOT/users-develop-20190806.111405-21-stubs.jar```. On page of artifact displayes Module ID: 
```com.exampleapp:users:develop-20190806.111405-21:stubs```. What part of this link is the right of repositoryRoot? Now I got next exaption: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for ```[com.exampleapp:users]```

Comment: If you need to provide the link to your artifactory root. I have no idea how it's setup. It needs to be a link where one can get the artifact via http get.

Comment: Marcin, please continue help with posibility to take JSON stubs :) I've spot that in LOCAL mode stub's JSONs can be taken from local m2repository in Test class in method with annotation Test via StubFinder but if I tried to take stubs using main programm (write controller for example), StubFinder doesn't find any stubs. I provided the same AutoConfigureStubRunner properties, same ContextConfiguration for test class and for main app and get different results. How can I take stab's JSONs in main application?

Comment: I'm sorry I completely don't understand your problem. You can already fetch JSON stubs, I don't understand what is not working fine for you.

Comment: I have task to create app which will provide stub's JSONs via REST. I fetch JSONs in test class during passing tests, but in main application StubFinder doesn't get stubs JSONs.

Comment: https://github.com/VladimirNechiporyuk/stub_runner_server/tree/master/src
I've shared this project to github and hop it will help.
In test class AdminControllerIntegrationTest.java method System.out.println("\n\n>>>>>>>>My stubs via stub finder:\n\n" + stubFinder.getContracts().toString()) returns {many jsons from stubs}
But in main folder in StubsController.java class method stubFinder.getContracts().toString() - returned empty {}

Comment: So, Marcin, have you any idea about getting JSONs from stubs via StubsController.java class? I'll be grateful to you for help :)

Comment: Your github project doesn't exist. Also, since you've mentioned that you need to run a server that will fetch the stubs, then why won't you just use the Stub Runner fat jar (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-boot-how-fat-jar)? If it's not a standalone server that you need then just use the standard `@AutoConfigureStubRunner` without any explicit stub server being started. Please read the documentation.

Comment: It's my folt to not making repository public before, sorry:) I have already make it public. https://github.com/VladimirNechiporyuk/stub_runner_server. About reading documentation, I already read many pages from different resources and didn't find solution (I tryed many variants during week) and may be I overlooked the solution

Comment: You're using SPEL inside of ids (https://github.com/VladimirNechiporyuk/stub_runner_server/blob/master/src/test/java/com/exampleproject/stub_runner_server/AdminControllerIntegrationTest.java#L15) I'm not sure that we support it.

Comment: Ok, Marcin, I won’t torment you anymore)) Thanks for your spend time)

Comment: No problem. Can we mark this as answered (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't solve my problem but I don't know what information I can provide you for getting the solution((

Comment: The solution is not to use the SPEL expression in your stub id. You could use a JUnit rule and resolve a system property at runtime and attach it to your ID. If that's not the solution you were expecting then I can't help you ATM.